# Speeding up breakpoints in launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

In the last few weeks, I have been getting a notification on my Visual Studio Code:

> It's taking a while to configure your breakpoints. You can speed this up by updating the 'outFiles' in your launch.json.

I do not currently have an outFiles section in my launch.json. Should I consider adding this section, or could I get away with ignoring the notification?

This is my launch.json:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/index.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "timeout": 10000,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "trace": true,
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_source-map-discovery) help?